# XmlDocument Load Xml Without Validating

Tags: .net, xml

Have some bad xml , like:

```
NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemTechLimit8&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemCommercLimit8&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;AoValue8&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;/tr>&lt;tr>&lt;td id=&quot;DemInt9&quot;>8:00 - 9:00
&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemValue9&quot;>1&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemValueDeclined9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;CalcValue9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;LoadLoss9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemTechLimit9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemCommercLimit9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;AoValue9&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;/tr>&lt;tr>&lt;td id=&quot;DemInt10&quot;>9:00 - 10:00
&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemValue10&quot;>1&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemValueDeclined10&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;CalcValue10&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;LoadLoss10&quot;>NaN&lt;/td>&lt;td id=&quot;DemTechLimit10
```

How can i load it into XmlDocument, without any validating or dtd?

It is for digital signing purposes, so i can not replace special character or format it.

Here is example on JS, but i need .NET code:

```
xmldoce.async = false;
xmldoce.validateOnParse = false;
xmldoce.preserveWhiteSpace = false;
xmldoce.resolveExternals = false;
xmldoce.loadXML(...);
```

**EDIT:**

I need to load that content to object, defined by schema:

```
<complexType name="ObjectType" mixed="true">
<sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
</sequence> 
</complexType>
```

Maybe it is possible withou XmlDocument?

Comment: If it isn't valid xml, it won't be loaded into `XmlDocument` until you clean it up. Even [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will have a tough time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an xml .It seems to be an html. You can decode it as

```
var html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
```

and most probably you will need [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it.

Below example extracts some useful things from your string

```
var html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
              .Select(tr=>tr.Descendants("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList())
              .ToList();
```